# How do I layer an image underneath specific text instead of a background?

Tags: html, css, image, css-layer

Sorry if the initial title has some poor wording, but what I am asking is how to add an image underneath of text in CSS/HTML. Please note I am referring to a specific location on the screen, rather than a background image -- kind of similar to how most titles in Google Sites contain an image/design underneath of the title.

I tried changing around the order of each element on both the HTML and CSS end of the site, but no matter the order I had the elements; the text still didn't appear, with the image covering it.

As well I tried testing around with positioning, but the image still appears on top of the text -- and the position was already set to absolute lol, this being a layering issue not a positioning issue

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask]. If you are absolute positioning use z-index to determine what goes on top. The higher the number the higher the layer.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of an example view? I am having a hard time understanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you saying you want the image to stay in the same place in the viewport - possibly for example with text scrolling 'over' it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To layer elements with CSS, you can set the `position` to `absolute` and you can lower the `z-index`. Elements with a lower `z-index` will have a lower layer on the page. For example, a `z-index` of 1 will appear over a `z-index` of -1.

```css
#my-img {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#my-text {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

In the code above, the text will appear above the image.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try `background-image` in css

```
background-image: url('img_url');
```

I will work fine